# Share source files between android development projects

Tags: android, compilation, compiler-errors

I have two apps (in packages `com.me.app` and `com.me.app.dev`, in two directories `android-app/` and `android-app-dev/`) and I want to **share code between the two apps**.

For example, I want to include `import com.me.app.MyService` in `android-app-dev/com/me/app/dev/MyServiceDev.java`.

I know that **paths must be set correctly**, but I cannot get it right.

For example, I have tried including `android.library.reference.2=../android-app/` in `android-app-dev/project.properties`, but this leads to numerous compilation errors, such as

```
[aapt] android-app/res/layout/main.xml:85: error: No resource identifier
found for attribute 'description' in package 'com.me.app'
```

(I should stress that I can compile `com.me.app`, without any problems, i.e., I can compile from `android-app/`)

**How should I configure project.properties?**

Comment: The solution appears to be non-trivial. In particular, `com.me.app`, respectively `com.me.app.dev`, define `com.me.app.R`, respectively  `com.me.app.dev.R`. Hence, classes in `com.me.app` must refer to  `com.me.app.R`, whereas classes in `com.me.app.dev` must refer to  `com.me.app.dev.R`. Thus, the problem appears to be non-trivial.

Comment: I looked into defining `com.me.app` as a library (by adding `android.library=true` to `android-app/project.properties`), but then  `com.me.app` cannot be installed, because it is a library, rather than an application.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily solved using flavors in gradle (their were thought for that).

Using flavors you can configure several kinds of compilation (development, release, provider1, provider2) and you only have to set an specific folder tree for sources and gradle will compile the appropriate sources and resources (like strings or drawables) depending on your compilation mode.

You can read more about them [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html), [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) or [here](http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/).

I hope this would help you!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm currently using Ant. Does Ant also have this property? (I'm looking for a quick fix and changing my build tool probably isn't a quick fix.)

Comment: I havent worked with ant. Maven has profiles so i thinks it should hace something similar

Comment: Switching to Gradle, from Ant, is probably a medium-term solution, since it seems to have many advantages as a build tool. In the short-term, I'd like to get the code up and running. (I'm tempted to copy-and-paste files as a quick fix! This would be a bad idea for many reasons.)

Comment: Gradle+android studio it's the best option without any doubt !!! Please, mark the answer as the correct or vote up un case it would help you. If you need any more.. ;)

Comment: I don't use IDEs, so Android Studio isn't a solution for me. (I'll try Gradle in the future.)

Comment: Flavors is a gradle feature, not Android Studio. My recommended full stack are both, but my documented answer was all about gradle's way (what is a real solution for your question, maybe not for your case). But it's up to you. Everyone of us has different needs